# Why KDE cannot change brightness, while Unity can? Macbook Air 4,2

Tags: kubuntu, kde, brightness, macbook, macbook-air

I installed Ubuntu and KDE too on my MacBook Air 4,2, but I realised I cannot change brightness in KDE. In Unity, it works without problem. Other keyboard keys works properly, sound, play, etc., but I cannot change brightness in KDE. I tried KDE4.8.4 and KDE4.9 beta.
Thx

Answer (score 0):

I have laptop brightness buttons working. If I wouldn't I'd play with

```
/etc/acpi/events/asus-brightness-down
/etc/acpi/events/asus-brightness-up
```

files (do You have them - or some similar files there?). See what is written there - some shell commands.

Also in the old days bright could have been controlled with:

```
echo -n 100 > /proc/acpi/video/VGA/LCD/brightness # sets br to 100%
```

but now the mechanism is changed.